# Confusing while Passing data between the components

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I am new in angular 6, I am creating the project using angular 6. I am coming to the problem while sharing the data.

Here is my code:

1) Component Sidebar:

```
selectedCategory(type:any) {
    this.loginService.categoryType = type; // need to pass this data
}
```

2) List Comp:

```
export class ListPostsComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        // here I need the data
    }
}
```

3) Service:

```
export class LoginService {
    categoryType:any;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your service make `categoryType` a `Subject` and call the `next()` when you need to pass data to another component:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LoginService {
  private categoryType: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  public categoryType$ = this.categoryType.asObservable();

  public sendData(data: any){
      this.categoryType.next(data);
  }
}
```

Now in your Component Sidebar, you need to inject the service `LoginService` and call the `sendData` method:

```
constructor(private loginService: LoginService ){ }
selectedCategory(type:any) {
    this.loginService.sendData(type); 
}
```

Since a `Subject` is both an Observer and an Observable you can subscribe to the Subject and listen for changes in the component you wish to receive the data:

```
export class ListPostsComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private loginService: LoginService ){ }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.loginService.categoryType$.subscribe((data) => {
           //use your data here
        });
    }
}
```

Here is a working example of the above solution in Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2sld4k?file=src%2Fapp%2Floginservice.service.ts

Comment: getting error 
this.loginService.subscribe((data) => {
           //use your data here
        });

Comment: @Karan did you add the import `import { Subject } from 'rxjs';` ?

Comment: Property 'categoryType' is private and only accessible within class 'LoginService'.

Comment: not works...The problem is both of the sidebar and home components loads at same time, how the home compoments reintilize after clicking the button from sidebar component

Comment: @Karan this looks like a different issue from what you mentioned in the question, my question is were you able to get the data from the `ListPostsComponent ` component?

Comment: My problem is to send the data from sidebar to list componet, the data is reaching into service but not in list

Comment: when i click on button the sidebar components call and then pass the data to list component , now the problem is both component loads

Comment: Try this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2sld4k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: I have demonstrated my example in the above Stackblitz